# Transferring rig weights from one mesh to another in blender 2.76

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I've recently started using blender in order to create my own models for games and such. I have created a model, rigged it, created clothes separately and now I want to add those clothes to my model so that it moves with the rig without the skin poking through.

So there are many solutions that use the weight transfer tool but I can't seem to get this working with blender 2.76. I parent the rig to the clothes with empty weight groups under the deform option. I then, selecting the mesh and then the piece of clothing, go to weight paint mode and choose the 'transfer weights' option under the tools section but the weights dont actually get transfered, nothing happens.

All the tutorials online use previous versions of blender and so the interface of options when choosing to transfer weights is different which could mean that I am just selecting the wrong options (I tried messing with them but nothing works).

Any help will be appreciated. I can post pictures later if need be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a proper explanation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719718/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76/34760742#34760742

Answer (score 6):

Im using 2.79, they did change it after 2.76. Heres how it works now. Once you have parented the desired mesh to the rig with empty groups. You have to select first the weighted mesh and then the desired mesh for the transfer. Then go into weight paint mode. Then change the following two settings, source layers and destination layers. Source layers needs to be set to "By Name". Destination needs to be set to "All Layers". Once these two settings are changed the transfer will automatically occur.

[image]