# Cannot transfer weights from objects

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

im trying to transfer weights from one object to another. Ive downloaded and edited this guy and i wanna use the skeleton of the girl because it has very cool IK, and im not proficient enought to make an IK skelly by myself. When i use automatic weights it looks kinda decent but it has some horrible morphs around some of the muscle areas.

i have also tried these two tutorials, and none worked. im currently using blender 2.78.

[Transferring rig weights from one mesh to another in blender 2.76](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719718/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76

can someone help me to find a way to transfer weights from the girl to the guy?.

Comment: Here is the file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5999" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5999/)

Comment: The two meshes have different vert count, so it won't work.

Comment: do they have to have the same exact amount of vertices? how can i fix that?

Comment: According to my knowledge, it can't be fixed. You can make similar IK rigs with Manuel Bastioni Lab. Give it a try: https://github.com/NumesSanguis/FACSvatar/releases/download/v0.3.4-alpha-release/manuelbastionilab_161a.zip